# How do I use <slot> in templates?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to understand the usage of [`<slot>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot) in Vue templates. The way I understand it, slots can be used to pass along child content in the component to the template.

Below is a short, minimum working example ([also on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMVBmQ)).

```js
Vue.component('mine', {
  template: '#mine'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app' 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="mine">
  <h1>this is it</h1>
  <slot></slot>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <mine>
    <p>why isn't this displayed</p>
  </mine>
</div>
```

I would expect the output to be like this:

```
<h1>this is it</h1>
<p>why isn't this displayed</p>
```

However, what happens is the second line does not appear when the page is rendered.

Comment: Try with <slot name="mine">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates need to have a single root DOM element.  Looks like Vue was just taking the `h1` as the whole template and discarding the rest:

```js
Vue.component('mine', {
  template: '#mine'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app' 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="mine">
  <div>
    <h1>this is it</h1>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <mine>
    <p>why isn't this displayed</p>
  </mine>
</div>
```

(Using a "developer mode" version of the library will give you better error messages about this sort of thing:)

```js
Vue.component('mine', {
  template: '#mine'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app' 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="mine">
    <h1>this is it</h1>
    <slot></slot>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <mine>
    <p>why isn't this displayed</p>
  </mine>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on a development build; this is extremely helpful. In trying to learn Vue, I've scratched my head at a number of things that don't work but also don't throw errors or warnings.

Comment: Yeah, dev mode in vue has unusually good error messages; I wish other frameworks took as much care about that sort of thing.